# What exactly are bpp and prec records of opj_image_comp structure

Tags: jpeg2000, openjpeg

According to the doxygen documentation (http://www.openjpeg.org/doxygen/structopj__image__comp.html), the opj_image_comp structure contains two fields that are confusing me:

- prec: precision
- bpp: image depth in bits

Based on just this info, I would assume that an image with 8 bit pixels (0-255) would have a bpp=8.  But when I decompressed some stock 8-bit mono .j2k files, I was finding that prec=8 and bpp=0.

So, what exactly do prec and bpp contain?

I am using OpenJPEG v2.3 if that has any impact on the answer.

Thanks much.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find additional info with more digging.

The prec field contains the number of bits used to encode the image. This corresponds to the lower 7 bits of the Ssiz field in the Image and Tile Size (SIZ) marker segment.

I have not figured out what the bpp field in the OpenJPEG struct opj_image_comp_t actually contains.

Comment: hi! don't suppose you've gained any more insight into this?  I've noticed https://github.com/uclouvain/openjpeg/blob/master/tests/test_tile_encoder.c only sets `prec` and has a comment saying "bpp useless" but would be nice to what it's useless for

Comment: The only place I could find bpp "used" was in src/lib/openjp2/j2k.c.  It was used when verifying that the image components were compatible with a specified cinema or IMF profile.  But beyond that, I could not find them actually being used when performing the compression.

Comment: have searched around a bit more but didn't find anything so created an issue with the project: https://github.com/uclouvain/openjpeg/issues/1379

Comment: just heard back, and `bpp` is disappearing: https://github.com/uclouvain/openjpeg/pull/1383

Answer (score 0):

The `bpp` is a redundant field and shouldn't be used.  To encourage this, it has recently been [deprecated by the author](https://github.com/uclouvain/openjpeg/pull/1383), saying:

> bpp was redundant with prec, and almost never set by the library, except
> by opj_image_create(). This change should hopefully not impact existing,
> working, users of the API, which should already have used prec to get
> things working.

As per the question, `prec` is the per-channel bit-depth.  So, for an unsigned channel, valid values would be in [0, 2<sup>prec</sup>-1].